# Rails Nested Model filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-forms

I'm stucked in Nested models.
 I have some nested habtm models. The problem is how do i filter habtm nested model results in views.

for example:

```
#Company.rb
has_many :company_categories
has_many :categories, :through => :company_categories, :order => 'name'

#companies/_form.html.erb (in edit mode)
...
<%= select_tag :filter_by_category, options_for_select(...) %>
...
<%= f.fields_for :company_categories do |builder %>
  render 'category_fields', :f => builder
<% end %>
```

i want to filter results with filter_by_category parameter/

sorry for my ancient english.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to change the options as soon as the filter_by_category field changes. You can easily setup a small jQuery Ajax script that asks the server for the options depending on the value selected.

You could read more about jQuery and it's Ajax stuff here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks for reply but this is not a javascript question. i want to filter categories from server side (<%= f.fields_for :company_categories do |builder %>" i mean at this line) via filter_by_category param

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean... the ajax request is to filter them as soon as the element changes, so you request the server to give you the new list of the categories based on the new selected value.If you have the filter_by_category param before rendering the page, then you could have it inside a collection and use the "options_from_collection_for_select" helper method